# Compare CSV files from two dropdowns Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

How can I create a shiny app with two dropdown menus with csv files from ./data folder then read those Csv and compare differences?

A user selects CSV from two dropdown menus then automatically generates differences

UI.R

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Automated Data Dictionary Comparison"),
    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel(

        selectInput(inputId = 'Dic1',
                    label = 'Choose First Data Dictionary:',
                    choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                         full.names = FALSE,
                                         recursive = FALSE)),
        selectInput(inputId = 'Dic2',
                    label = 'Choose Second Data Dictionary:',
                    choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                         full.names = FALSE,
                                         recursive = FALSE))
      ),

      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('contents')
      )
    )
  )
)
```

SERVER.R

```
Library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

 server <-  function(input, output) {

   dataset <- reactive({
     infile <- input$Dic1

     if (is.null(infile)){
       return(NULL)
     }
     read.csv(infile[[1]])
   })

   output$contents <- renderDataTable({

     #x <- dataset()
     Diff <- render_diff(diff_data(data_ref=input$DIC1, data = input$DIC2),
     Diff
   })

 }
```

Comment: This is a very broad question asking someone to write a small program for you. Can you show any code you have written to achieve this?  Then SO can guide you/ at least narrow down where you are having trouble.

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see here, what you are doing is that you are correctly creating your reactive dataset object **dataset** (for 1 of your input files though not both), but you are not using this later on, when you want to generate the differences table (which again needs to be a reactive component as it will be generated from 2 reactive ones - **dataset1** and **dataset2**).

Something like this should do the trick though (wrap it inside the server function):

```
# Parse first file
dataset1 <- reactive({
  infile <- input$Dic1

  if (is.null(infile)){
    return(NULL)
  }
  x <- read.csv(infile[[1]])
  x
})
# Parse second file
dataset2 <- reactive({
  infile <- input$Dic2

  if (is.null(infile)){
    return(NULL)
  }
  x <- read.csv(infile[[1]])
  x
})
# Create comparison table (reactive as both of its elements are reactive)
diff <- reactive({
  x <- render_diff(diff_data(data_ref=dataset1(), data=dataset2()))
  x
})
#Output
output$contents <- renderDataTable({
  diff()
})
```

Check the above and let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: *Error in file: cannot open the connection*  error I see on mainpanel once I select CSV files from drop down menu

Comment: Try with:
`x <- read.csv(infile[[1]])`
for each of the reactive datasets instead (check my edit on the post).

Comment: Also, have you tried just inputting one of the datasets from a single drop-down and outputting it on your `output$contents` alone -without any changes- to verify your code that far works?

Comment: Let me try that out but I will give you a thumbs up for helping out

Comment: Cheers - lets get it to work though! Let me know if the first attempt works and if you get your dataset in as expected. If your input works, the rest should follow.

Comment: Hello Steve need some help bro

Comment: Hey! SO does not allow for direct messages, so just post your question and give me a link to take a look!

Comment: is concerning the same question here, I am experiencing an error when trying to compare the two csv in a dropdown menu, error says  (No file in directory, error is fike: cannot open the connection). Yet I have all files in data directory

Comment: Add a line to set your working directory in the beginning like so:
`setwd("./data")` (or whatever your working dir is) and try again.